# CI get_instance return null

Tags: codeigniter

I using CI for my framework, and i don't know what is the error of this code

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class RajaOngkir extends CI_Controller {

private $api_key, $base_url;

public function __construct() {
    // Pastikan bahwa PHP mendukung cURL
    if (!$this->is_curl_exists()) {
        log_message('error', 'cURL Class - PHP was not built with cURL enabled. Rebuild PHP with --with-curl to use cURL.');
    }
    $this->_ci=&get_instance();
    var_dump($this->_ci);
    $this->_ci->load->config('rajaongkir', TRUE);
    // Pastikan Anda sudah memasukkan API Key di application/config/rajaongkir.php
    if ($this->_ci->config->item('api_key', 'rajaongkir') == "") {
        log_message("error", "Harap masukkan API KEY Anda di config.");
    } else {
        $this->api_key = $this->_ci->config->item('api_key', 'rajaongkir');
        $this->base_url = $this->_ci->config->item('api_base_url', 'rajaongkir');
    }
}
```

when i access it using web browser, its giving me error

```
Severity: Notice

   Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/rajaongkir.php

Line Number: 22

Fatal error: Call to a member function config() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Koen_CI\application\controllers\rajaongkir.php on line 22
```

i think the error is when i call this->_ci=&get_instance. because its returning null value.

how to fix it?

Comment: If you are working inside a controller, you should `$this->function()` directly instead of `$this->ci->function()`

Comment: CI_Controller is already part of Codeigniter super object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the _ci variable in the class:

```
private $api_key, $base_url;
```

To

```
private $api_key, $base_url, $_ci;
```

But don't do that. As others mentioned in the comment, if you're in a controller, just use `$this->something` directly instead of `$this->_ci`. You should only use `get_instance()` when you're outside the CI structure (e.g. in a helper file).